# OpenModelica errors "Too few rows in data_2 matrix"

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have tried to simulate this simple example (in OpenModelica 1.9.1 Beta1 (r18938)):

model daadd

parameter Real tw1=32.1;

parameter Real tw2=36.4;

Real tk2;

equation

1=(tw2-tw1)/(2.3*log10((tk2-tw1)/(tk2-tw2)));

end sjoelund.se;

end daadd;

And then I got this message: `Too few rows in data_2 matrix`.
Then I also got another error-message:

```
LOG_NLS        | warning     | Error solving nonlinear system Nonlinear function (residualFunc5, size 1) at time 0 Debug more 
stdout        | warning     | Error in initialization. Storing results and exiting. 
Use -lv=LOG_INIT -w for more information. 
Process crashed 
Simulation process exited with code -1
```

Comment: You can format text as code to make the text more readable. Learn more here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help or just use the buttons in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with [r21400](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/changeset/21400), OpenModelica will handle the inverse of log10. The non-linear solver has trouble finding the solution because a lot of numbers are not valid input for log10 (and it is quite hard to try to numerically linearise it).

The generated code is now:

```
tk2 = (tw2 * 10.0 ^ ((tw2 - tw1) / 2.3) - tw1) / (-1.0 + 10.0 ^ ((tw2 - tw1) / 2.3))
```

Comment: I'm a beginner and I don't understand what should  I to do with r21400?

Comment: r21400 is the version number of the OpenModelica Nightly Build. The currently available version is r21397. You can check that here. https://www.openmodelica.org/index.php/developersresources/nightly-builds

Comment: Did I understand you correctly? I should start OpenModelica Nightly Build version is r21397 and will insert this code  r21400?  https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/browser/trunk/Compiler/BackEnd/ExpressionSolve.mo?rev=21400?

Comment: You just wait 24 hours for the next build. A version >= 21400 will work.